# Where to ask a question about language/library limitations and alternatives?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about how to achieve specific functionality in Python and if it's not possible, if I should switch to another language, e.g. JavaScript.  Here: [How to plot graphs nicely in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500501/how-to-plot-graphs-nicely-in-python#)
I got an answer that indeed it's not worth it and it's an industry practice to use a specific JavaScript library.  From my point of view, the answer is perfect - and it matches my observations as well.

However, the question was voted as off-topic by 5 people.  From my point of view both the question and the answer were very specific.  Now, I don't understand where and how to ask this type of questions in the future...

Comment: What answer?  I don't see one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, what you're asking for boils down to a library request.  You want a library that can accomplish your four requirements, and while you've tried both Networkx and Graphviz, they're not entirely working out for you.

The reason that this is going to be an issue is due to the sorts of responses it will encourage.  You're going to get a lot of answers to the effect of:

> Try PyGraphLib v1.4, it can accomplish all of that and draw the nodes in the shape of a star, too.

...which isn't what we want around here.

If you personally want that, you could give [Sofware Recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) a try and see if you can get an answer there.

Comment: Did not know about Software Recs.  Thanks a lot!